# getting automatically the initials of names

Tags: loops, xstring

This sounds like some basic stuff, and yet I cannot manage to find a solution, packaged or native.

I have documents with people who have from 2 to 4 names (typical Danish name could be Søren Jens Sørensen Hjortshøj).

Can someone suggest a command that would extract the initials (first letter) of each of those words ? I know of the package xstring to extract the first letter. The trouble is looping on the words, as I don't know the number in advance.

So the command \initials would act like this :

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\initials}{m} {
Some code
}
...
\ingenior{Søren Jens Sørensen Hjortshøj}

....

\initials{\ingenior} is SJSH.
```

Comment: `\initials{\author}` will *never* work, unless you completely redefine `\author`.

Comment: @campa : why is that ? Could I use another variable that is not part of the LaTeX standard ?

(I tend to define \ingenior{Søren Sørensen}, I can use that \ingenior everywhere and then later I assign \author{\ingenior})

Comment: @22decembre, if you just have a handful of names, just code as many \newcommand-s to just supply the initials, which you code by hand.

Comment: Usually `\author` is the command to set the author (usually by redefining the internal `\@author`). `\author` never returns the author. So `\initials{\author}` does not make sense.

Comment: @22decembre The `\author` command doesn't contain the author name but set the variable `\@author`. You should rewrite your example with `\initials{\ingenior}`.

Comment: @22decembre Take a look how `\author` been defined. Try `\ShowCommand\author` and check the log file, the result is `> \author =macro: #1->\gdef \@author {#1}.`

Comment: I modified my request as to not refer to \author.

Comment: How do you recommend the initials for Jean le Rond D'Alembert be written or Jan van Riebeeck?  You should be more specific for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a modified version of my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/705530/. The idea is to create a recursive function that prints the first character, splits the string on the first space, and calls itself on the rest if the rest is not empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\initials}{m}{%
    \StrLeft{#1}{1}%           % print first character
    \StrBehind{#1}{ }[\rest]%  % copy everything after first space into \rest
    \IfStrEq{\rest}{}{}{%      % if rest is empty (first {}) do nothing (second {}),
                               % which will stop the recursive loop.
    \initials{\rest}%          % else: call the function again on the rest
    }%
}

\def\ingenior{Søren Jens Sørensen Hjortshøj}

\begin{document}

The initials of \ingenior\ are \initials{\ingenior}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this will break if the name starts with a non-ascii char, try e.g. with `Émile`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Also  initials for Jean le Rond D'Alembert  or Jan van Riebeeck! At minimum one should give an optional parameter. Also better to move to l3 which can handle strings and iteration better. Names are cultural specific so a method to handle exceptions should be provided.

Comment: There is a serious chance that a dane will have a non-ascii character as an initial (ø,æ and å are regular letters of the danish alphabet, they have correspondences in other nordic languages.)

Comment: @Ulrike It didn't break, I tried (with pdfLaTeX) `\def\ingenior{Émile Søren Jens Sørensen Hjortshøj}` and I got the correct result ÉSJSH.

Comment: @22decembre also `\def\ingenior{Øren Åjens Sørensen Hjortshøj}` and `\def\ingenior{Æmile Øren Åjens Sørensen Hjortshøj}` work fine and produce the correct initials, in pdfLaTeX as well as XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Not with pdflatex, sorry. That can't be.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry to disappoint you but I'm looking at the result right now :) Maybe a version difference? I used `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)` and `Package: xstring 2021/07/21 v1.84`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it _does_ fail with even more exotic characters though, such as āēīǎ, as noted in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646864/.

Comment: your system is too old ... In a current LaTeX utf8 chars are protected and it won't work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so your system is too new then :)

Comment: Actually, I use LuaLaTeX and it works.

For all I care, it's enough as of now.

Comment: @22decembre even with lualatex you can get problems if the initial uses an combining accent.